# Python Facebook API

Tags: python, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm writing a script to pull a given person's Facebook profile pictures. I figure I'll have to work with a Facebook API, but exactly how would I go about that?

More specifically, the way this would work is that the program would get a person's first name, last name, and email. Since email is the most accurate way to pull a person's Facebook, it'd pull it by email first; and if that doesn't work, try the first name last name combo, with possible other parameters such as college attending.

Comment: Search in Github, there are more than a few Python SDKs for interacting with the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

Python may not be the best language to try this in. Facebook lists no native or third-party support for Python in its API documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks

...

However, There appears to be an in-development Facebook SDK for Python, which may have some of what you are looking for:

https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Get that package installed, and then start looking in the API reference there for more info. The `get_object` command may be helpful, although its described use does not cover getting other users' pictures through the API.